# mysqli database table join with summation value in codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, date

Table name = **product**

```
---------------------
ID       Product Name
---------------------
1       Samsung
2       iPhone
3       HTC
```

Table name = **Sell**

```
-----------------------------------------------------
ID       Product_id       Price($)       Date(d/m/y)
-----------------------------------------------------
1       1                  400           11/11/2017
2       2                  500           11/11/2017
3       3                  450           11/11/2017
4       2                  500           11/11/2017
5       2                  500           11/11/2017
6       1                  400           11/11/2017
7       1                  400           11/11/2017
8       3                  450           11/11/2017
9       1                  400           12/11/2017
10      2                  500           12/11/2017
11      3                  450           12/11/2017
12      2                  500           12/11/2017
13      2                  500           12/11/2017
14      1                  400           12/11/2017
15      1                  400           12/11/2017
16      3                  450           12/11/2017
17      1                  400           13/11/2017
18      2                  500           13/11/2017
19      3                  450           13/11/2017
20      2                  500           13/11/2017
21      2                  500           13/11/2017
22      1                  400           13/11/2017
23      1                  400           13/11/2017
24      3                  450           13/11/2017
```

I want to show on browser like this table:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Ser No       Product Name       Date       Total Product       Total Price($)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            Samsung          11/11/2017       3                    1200
2            iPhone           11/11/2017       3                    1500
3            HTC              11/11/2017       2                     900
4            Samsung          12/11/2017       3                    1200
5            iPhone           12/11/2017       3                    1500
6            HTC              12/11/2017       2                     900
7            Samsung          13/11/2017       3                    1200
8            iPhone           13/11/2017       3                    1500
9            HTC              13/11/2017       2                     900
```

#### Is it possible?

#### if it is possible then how it is possible with codeigniter?

Comment: It can be done with simple join query with some aggregate functions

Comment: Please give a that join query. when i apply query then summation is not working.

Comment: *when i apply query then summation is not working* show us your attempt which doesn't work

Comment: "Ser No" correspond to what ?

Answer (score 0):

Except the first column something like this would work :

```
   SELECT 
      Product.Name,
      Sell.DateSell,
      Count(ProductId) as total,
      Sum(Sell.Price) as total_price,
    FROM Product
    INNER JOIN Sell on Sell.Product_id = Product.ID
   GROUP BY Product.Name, Sell.DateSell
```

If you want to add a row number like 'Ser No' :

```
  SELECT 
      @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS 'Ser No',
      t.Name as 'Product Name',
      t.DateSell as 'Date',
      t.total as 'Total Product',
      t.total_price as 'Total Price'
  FROM 
  ( SELECT 
      Product.Name,
      Sell.DateSell,
      Count(ProductId) as total,
      Sum(Sell.Price) as total_price,
    FROM Product
    INNER JOIN Sell on Sell.Product_id = Product.ID
   GROUP BY Product.Name, Sell.DateSell
  ) t, (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```